# Open new window, and scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I need to open a window after the dom is loaded, and scroll the y position to the element, preferably centered on the screen. I looked on stack overflow and I put something together with the bits i found.

The problem with this is that it's using a timer to see my element is available, and it is really slow - altering the interval time does not effect the speed at all. Also, it does not work in IE and i need it to. thought on this?

```
    linkToComment: function(e){
        var link = 'https://****';
        var commentId = 21

        var w = window.open(link);          
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if ( $(w.document.body).find("div[data-commentoriginalid=" + commentId + "]")) {
              $(w.document.body).animate({
                  scrollTop: ( $(w.document.body).find("div[data-commentoriginalid=" + commentId + "]").offset().top)
              },500);
              clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 500)



    },
```

Comment: add a hash to your urlElement `link = 'http://****#element'` and add the corresponding id on the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the interval:

```
 $(w.document).ready(function () {
     $(w.document.body).animate({
       scrollTop: ( $(w.document.body).find("div[data-commentoriginalid=" + commentId + "]").offset().top)
     },500);
 });
```

but I don't understand why would you make this scroll from the parent window, instead of adding the javascript to the opened window...

Comment: it's confusing, but this actually runs on the opened window.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your problem correctly. You are running javascript in URL A, and opening a new window using that javascript (URL B). When URL B loaded, you want to scroll the window which holds URL B, to a specific point? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the code/source in the child window? If I was doing this, I would add an onload handler in the child window, rather than trying to control it from the parent. If you need to pass in a variable to the child from the parent, you could either use a querystring or a hash parameter.

e.g. mysite.com#2345

And then pick that id up in the child window, select the element with that ID and scroll to it.

Remember - the parent window could be closed by the user while the child window is opening meaning the timer would be killed.

Comment: I do have access to the code. Can you provide a code sample?